# Find duplicate values within 3 columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the below:

```
Site | Name | ID
A | Mike | 1
A | Mary | 2
A | Mary | 3
B | Mary | 1
B | Rich | 2
```

I'd like to find all the duplicate Name's within a Site.  So I'm trying to return:

```
Site | Name | ID
A | Mary | 2
A | Mary | 3
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Site, Name, ID
from table
group by ID having count(*) > 1
```

The results come back erroneously because it's counting Sites A & B together.  I would like to only find the duplicates for within each Site--not duplicates across Sites.

Comment: @Rawrplus What are you going to do with the `INNER JOIN`???

Comment: @Eric well the idea behind it is to determine where the duplicities occur and return just the matched values. Though yeah, in hindsight it s rather excessive and the `INNER JOIN` here actually kind of defeats the purpose. So yeah, proposition retracted, better solutions are found in answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` or `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.site = t.site and t2.name = t.name and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `NOT exists` with subquery `having`.

**the duplicate Name's within a Site**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Site varchar(5),
  Name varchar(5),
  ID int
);



insert into t values ('A','Mike', 1);
insert into t values ('A','Mary', 2);
insert into t values ('A','Mary', 3);
insert into t values ('B','Mary', 1);
insert into t values ('B','Rich', 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T t1 WHERE 
NOT exists
( 
  SELECT 1 
  FROM T tt
   where t1.name = tt.name 
  group by Name
  HAVING MIN(tt.ID) = t1.ID
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb8a3b/23/0)**:

```
| Site | Name | ID |
|------|------|----|
|    A | Mary |  2 |
|    A | Mary |  3 |
```

---

**find the duplicates for within each Site**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Site varchar(5),
  Name varchar(5),
  ID int
);



insert into t values ('A','Mike', 1);
insert into t values ('A','Mary', 2);
insert into t values ('A','Mary', 3);
insert into t values ('B','Mary', 1);
insert into t values ('B','Rich', 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM T t1 
WHERE not exists
( 
  SELECT 1 
  FROM T tt
  where t1.name = tt.name and t1.Site = tt.Site
  group by Name,Site
  HAVING MIN(tt.ID) = t1.ID
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb8a3b/23/0)**:

```
| Site | Name | ID |
|------|------|----|
|    A | Mary |  3 |
```